# how to do search on twitter user bios instead of user tweets?

Tags: php, twitter

I can't seem to find any detail on how to go about this in the official documentation, I tried looking into some results given by some of the methods hoping that I may be able to somehow use it but so far no luck.

Thanks in advance,
ayan

Comment: what do you mean, 'do search on twitter bio`? I don't think those bio fields are exposed

Comment: i mean, i want to be able to retrieve a list of users where the bio field in their twitter profiles has a match on the given search string, somewhat like tweepsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you're still looking.. I found out that users/search already looked in the bio. There's no seperate function to search for bio's only.